# CentOS hibernate state expires?

Tags: centos, power-management

I can successfully put my CentOS system in hibernate state. After a few minutes when I power up, all is as expected.  Desktop and running apps are preserved. Honkey-dory.

After a few hours of hibernate when I power back up the system goes through a full reboot.  Previous session not preserved.

This is my personal use machine.  I like to leave my work/apps open over night or though long lunches, or whenever.

Any thoughts why Hibernate will last for only so long?
Any suggestion where/what to look for?

CentOS 7.4, Linux 3.10.  Hardware MSI laptop PE70 6QE. Boot config acpi=off

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue after thorough debugging following the steps found [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/basic-pm-debugging.txt) .  In my case the backlit keyboard wasn't shutting off automatically as expected.  Seems to be related to MSI/Intel/Redhat combination malfunction.